# python seaborn shows bar plots as same height for different class

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to plot factor plots for my data. I tried doing it the below way but the chart values didn't turn out as expected.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subset_product':['A','A','A','B','B','C','C'],
                   'subset_close':[1,1,0,1,1,1,0]})

prod_counts = df.groupby('subset_product').size().rename('prod_counts')
df['prod_count'] = df['subset_product'].map(prod_counts)
g = sns.factorplot(y='prod_count',x='subset_product',hue='subset_close',data=df,kind='bar',palette='muted',legend=False,ci=None)
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

However, my plots all have the same height, meaning it didn't separate the data into '1' and '0'.

**Example:** For `A`, the blue bar should have height = 1, and the green bar should have height = 2.

[image]

Comment: Your code didn't work. You missed a `,` and `)` when you created `df`. And what is `df_merged`, is it `df`?

Comment: Yes it is df. i edited my code.

Comment: I think the bar is right,you can print df.

Comment: @WilliamFeirie this code works, but its not what im looking for. i want something slightly different. according to my data, and what i am looking for, the bars should have different heights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `'prod_count'`.

```
print(df)

#    subset_close subset_product  prod_count
# 0             1              A           3
# 1             1              A           3
# 2             0              A           3
# 3             1              B           2
# 4             1              B           2
# 5             1              C           2
# 6             0              C           2
```

You are telling seaborn that y is 3 when `subset_close == 1 & subset_product == A` and y is also 3 when `subset_close == 0 & subset_product == A`.

Below should do what you want.

```
# Count the number of each (`subset_close`, `subset_product`) combination.
df2 = df.groupby(['subset_product', 'subset_close']).size().reset_index(name='prod_count')
# Plot
g = sns.factorplot(y='prod_count', x='subset_product', hue='subset_close', data=df2, 
                   kind='bar', palette='muted', legend=False, ci=None)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()

print(df2)
#   subset_product  subset_close  prod_count
# 0              A             0           1
# 1              A             1           2
# 2              B             1           2
# 3              C             0           1
# 4              C             1           1
```

Comment: Thanks, why is there a need to reset_index?

Comment: I name the `count` column there.